Is the wrong size media filter installed in my new furnace?
The 20x20inch media filter doesn't seem to be the right size between the return plenum and the blower box. I am worried I am not getting the optimal airflow from return to supply. If its not would be the best size? 25x16inch? Can I ask the hvac installer to come back and install a media filter that would better fit the system if its the incorrect size?







just for clarity 20x20 and 25x16 give same opening size (400)

The filter tracks are are usually part of the airhandler and the filter is sized for the airhandler, not the return plenum. The plenum could be sized larger than needed just to accommodate the ducts being attached to it so if it a bit larger than the filter housing, that's OK.
